# Failed to convert DAV files to AVI using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, converters, avi, dav-file

I need to convert DAV files (files generated from security camera recorders) to AVI. I have a script that works, but it does not convert multiple files, and the files are not corrupted.
I use the following code:

```
for %% A IN (* .dav) DO ffmpeg -i "%% A" -vcodec libx264 "%% A.avi
```

```
FOLLOW LINK WITH DAV FILE : https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7agzzb8pe57uxy/DAV%20TEST.dav?dl=0
```

I get the following error on certain files:

**"Format dhav detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!"**

[image]

Comment: Provide a link to a dav file that isn't working in ffmpeg.

Comment: also try newer ffmpeg git version instead of that old one.

Comment: Hello, follow link to file dav : https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7agzzb8pe57uxy/DAV%20TEST.dav?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in a recent build from the git master branch:

- Windows: [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) or [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases)
- macOS: [evermeet.cx](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) or [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg)
- Linux: [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)

Do not choose the 4.2.1 release branch: it is too old.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. Now I found another problem, the files to be converted arrive in the folder every 30 minutes, when the 1st DAV file arrives the script is triggered by the task manager, the problem is that the conversion is fast, and I need that and the script is open waiting for the next file. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @AUDICOM Should be asked as a completely new, standalone question.